# Shabbat gentile worker different time zones halacha?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time-zone

Can a Jew, let's say on Friday in Eastern time New York 9AM (way before Shabbos) ask a gentile worker who is in Asia (where it is  already Shabbos) to do work for him?

Similar question [here](https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/time-zones/2023/02/12/) but I am talking about sending them a direct request like "respond to this email" or "bill this client".
Where there could also be large monetary benefit..

Are we stringent requiring both Shabbos timezones or just the Jew's.
Looking for sources.

Comment: Doesn't the article you quote have your answer? : "A Jew for whom it is not Shabbos can instruct a non-Jew in a different time zone to do work for him, if it is not publicly blatant at that locale that he is working for a Jew". It quotes B’tzel Hachochma 3:125; Shevet Halevi 3:172:4; Shemiras Shabbos K’hilchasa 31:27 as sources

Comment: I appreciate the edit, and to some extent, yes. The article primarily discusses indirect, small monetary acts, such as those in a call center, which are more subtle in nature. Would the same principles apply to actions like billing a client or processing a transaction, which involve direct requests? Does the level of directness make a difference, yes or no?
It's worth noting that the sources mentioned in the article were not used in the final psak explicitly.

Comment: Things like billing or processing a transaction are relatively abstract and not necessarily so much of a direct Halachic prohibition (except writing by hand) - all would be forbidden for a Jew (in a place where it is already Shabbos) but certainly less of an issue (if any) for a Jew to tell a non-Jew. So a better example might be a Jew (in non-Shabbos time zone) telling a non-Jew (in a Shabbos time zone) to do clear Melacha - e.g., light a fire, sew a garment, build something, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed by many recent Poskim with some being stringent and most being lenient. Here are some sources - its not a comprehensive list

רבבות אפרים (ח"ב סי' ק"י ד"ה ואיך) – "אם אצלו כבר לא שבת היכול לטלפן למקום שעדיין שבת לומר לעכו"ם שיעשה מלאכה עבורו. ומסתבר דהולכים בתר מקומו ... ולדידי כל דין זה לא ברור כל כך וטוב בודאי להמנע מזה".

שרגא המאיר (ח"ב סי' ס"ה) – "אבל במוצש"ק אם במקום הפאבריק הוא עוד יום, עוד שבת, אסור שם לעשות ולהניח לעכו"ם לעשות מלאכה מלאכה בהפאבריק, אעפ"י שבמקום שדר הבעה"ב הישראל כבר מאוחר בלילה וכבר מוצאי שבת, דכיון דבמקום הפאבריק הוא עוד שבת הוי כמו שהישראל אמר בחול לעכו"ם לעשות מלאכה בשבת".

באר משה (ח"ו קו"ע סי' מ"ט) – "נשאלתי אם שרי לצלצל על הטעלעפאן מארצות הברית בערב שבת ליוראפ לדבר עם נכרי אחר שם, ושם כבר הוא שבת קדש, וכן מהו במוצש"ק [מיוראפ לארה"ב]. השבתי פשוט שמותר ... משום דבר דבר ליכא דהלא אצל ישראל עדיין חול הוא וגם משום נראה כשלוחו אין כאן איסור דהלא אצל ישראל עדיין חול הוא ובעצמו שרי".

חלקת יעקב (ח"ג סי' ק"ו, או"ח סי' פ"ז) – "בשעה שלישראל בעצמו מותר לעשות ודאי אין שום סברא לאסור האמירה לעכו"ם אף שבמקום העכו"ם כבר שבת להישראלים הדרים שם, לגבי עכו"ם לא שייך שמירת שבת, אדרבה עכו"ם ששבת חייב מיתה".

הגריש"א זצ"ל (אשרי האיש או"ח ח"ב פרק ח' סעי' א', עי' רבבות אפרים ח"ח סי' קנ"ב אות ג') – "מותר להתקשר במוצאי שבת לגוי שנמצא במדינא אחרת, ואצל הגוי עדיין שבת, ולצוותו לעשות מלאכה, מאחר והמתקשר מתקשר בהיתר, ולגוי לא נוגע שבת".

ששכ"ה (פרק ל"א סעי' כ"ו [דפו"ח, סעי' כ"ז]) – "נכרי המטלפן מארץ שבה כבר נכנסה השבת, מותר ליהודי לשוחח עמו במקום שבו טרם נכנסה השבת, והוא הדין לגבי מוצאי-שבת ... ויתר על כן, אף מותר ליהודי שאצלו חול, לטלפן לנכרי שבמקומו שבת".

הגרח"ק זצ"ל(אסיפת יצחק ה' תשרי תשס"ז) – "שאלה: יהודי בארץ ישראל שאינו שבת בשבילו, האם מותר לו לצלצל לנכרי בחוץ לארץ בזמן שעדיין שבת שם, או אסור משום אמירה לנכרי. תשובה: יתכן שמותר".

ילקוט יוסף (סי' ש"ז אות ט', עמ' רמ"ג) – "ישראל המטלפן במוצ"ש מאר"י לחו"ל לגוי שנמצא בחו"ל, ורוצה לצוותו על עשיית איזה דבר לצורך הישראל, אע"פ שהגוי יעשה דברים אלו בשבת, אין בזה איסור אמירה לגוי, מאחר שבמקומו של הישראל כבר
יצאה שבת".

בן של השבט הלוי (שבט הלוי ח"ג סי' קע"ב) – "בספק דידן של צווי ממקום דעדיין לא נכנס שב"ק למקום שכבר נכנס שבת קודש והישראל מצווה לנכרי לעשות עתה והישראל במרחקים, יכול העכו"ם לעשות המלאכה בהיתר ויכול הישראל לצוות את העכו"ם לעשות ואף שבמקום העכו"ם כבר נתקדש היום".

ארחות שבת (פרק כ"ג סעי' קי"ג) – "ישראל הנמצא בארץ ישראל במוצאי שבת מותר להתקשר בטלפון לנכרי הנמצא בארצות הברית בשעה ששם עדיין שבת ולומר לו לעשות מלאכה עבורו, והטעם דכיון שבשעה זו מותר הישראל לעשות מלאכות לא מסתבר שיהיה אסור לו לומר לנכרי לעשות מלאכה עבורו אף שהנכרי נמצא במקום שבו עדיין לא יצאה השבת".

פסקי תשובות (דפו"ח הע' ד', עי' רמ"ו סוף אות ז', סי' רס"ג אות מ"ו, שם הע' ת"ה, עי' דפו"י סי' שד"מ אות ב') – "אבל מותר לומר דרך הטלפון וכדו' לנכרי הנמצא במקום שכבר שבת שיעשה מלאכה עבורו, ורשאי הנכרי לעשות המלאכה כל זמן שעדיין לא נכנס השבת במקום שהישראל שם, וכן במוצ"ש רשאי לומר לנכרי הנמצא במקום שעדיין שבת לעשות לו מלאכה, שו"ת חלקת יעקב ח"ג סי' ק"ו, שו"ת בצל החכמה ח"ג סי' קכ"ה".

Comment: this is a great answer. Please be mindful that a significant portion of Mi Yodeya readers are unable to read / translate Hebrew so you are more likely to score higher if you provide accompanying translation or suitable English summaries. Hatzlocho!